# Croissant baking temperature

Tags: baking, oven, french-cuisine

The short story - cant get the temp in the oven right. It gets too brown, if I lower the temperature it is not cooked and the internal structure is not as good as it should be.
The long story - so far I tried the following.

```
Preheat   Baking     Time     Internal structure         "Brownishness"
------     220 *      7min          10                       10
then       180 *      10min         10                       10
225*       180 *      20min         10                       10
230 |*|    180 |*|    15min         4                        10
250 | |    180 | |    18min         8                        8
```

Legend:
* - convection
|*| - top/bottom plus rear fan
| | - top/bottom

So, whatever I try I get them too dark or not cooked/ugly internal structure
What I'm missing here?

Comment: What happens if you lower the temperature and further extend the cooking time?

Comment: see line 3, 180 is low enough?

Comment: No, I mean, extend the cooking time until it's not undercooked.

Answer (score 1):

I know of 2 methods, the temperatures are for convection:

- Start at 200C and keep it 200C, turning it down if they start to get too brown
- Start at a high temperature and then lower it partway through, so you get an initial blast at about 200C for 5-6 minutes and then turn it down to 165C for another 9-10 minutes depending on size. This gives you the browning on the outside while cooking the inside

I don't do croissants often but when I do I use the second method.

Comment: will try it and report back